# MySQL - select from a set of unique values

Tags: mysql

I have a following setup:

```
---------------------
| user_id | list_id |
---------------------
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       2 |
|       3 |       2 |
---------------------
```

I need to select `user_id`'s by `list_id`, but only those which are unique in the table. So, in my example it should be only `user_id`'s 2 and 3.

What should I add to 
`select user_id from table where list_id=2` ?

Please help, I'm really stuck...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the `user_id` and take only those having at least one `list_id = 2` and in total only one record of this `user_id`

```
select user_id 
from table 
group by user_id
having sum(list_id = 2) > 0
and count(*) = 1
```

Comment: It's awesome, man! What a brain twister, but it works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select user_id from table  group by user_id having count(*) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use below query

```
select user_id ,count(*)
from table 
GROUP BY
     user_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: The `list_id` filter is missing here. Look at the @juergen d's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id from table  group by user_id having count(*)=1;
```

Comment: The `list_id` filter is missing here. Look at the @juergen d's answer